# Migration references dynamic storage inconsistent

Tags: python, django, django-storage

I want specific field in model to use either S3 storage (if settings has `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`) or fallback to `default_storage`. I'm using `django-storages`.

To implement this, in models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from .storage_backends import variativeStorage

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='/public', default='dummy-img.png', storage=variativeStorage())
```

storage_backends.py:

```py
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.conf import settings


def variativeStorage():
    """Return S3Boto3Storage if access key is defined.
    Fallback to default storage.
    """
    if hasattr(settings, 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') and settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:
        return S3Boto3Storage()
    return default_storage
```

It works great, but the problem is in migrations - it evaluates field `storage` on which django settings it currently has. So in case we don't have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `makemigrations` will do:

```
operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='profile',
            name='photo',
            field=models.ImageField(default='dummy-img.png', upload_to='/public'),
        ),
    ]
```

and in case it has:

```
operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='profile',
            name='photo',
            field=models.ImageField(default='dummy-img.png', storage=storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage(), upload_to='/public'),
        ),
    ]
```

So running server on production will trigger warning for missing migrations:

```
remote: Running migrations:
remote: No migrations to apply.
remote: Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
remote: Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Is there a consistent way of doing dynamic storage for field? How can I make lazy-evaluation of `variativeStorage` or maybe remove migration generation for that particular field?

Comment: Found an answer yet?

Comment: @CristianoCoelho no. Frankly, after couple of days trying, I left it with warning popping on production server.